# Foldable in-line regions / tags / comments

Tags: xml, logging, notepad++, notepad, folding

I would like to be able to fold/hide specific regions in the lines of my log files for example in a text-editor like Notepad++.
For example:

```
<time>09:55:37</time><place>Thread@ClassName.MethodName:LineNo</place> This is a log.
```

What I want to do is, to hide/fold the time and code place to dispay the log file like this for example:

```
<+ time><+ place> This is a log.
```

As I want to see them, I want to unfold/show the time or place by clicking on `+`.

Is there a way / text editor you know how to do this?